# How to make a website layout stay in place no matter how much you zoom in or out?

Tags: layout

I'm talking something like this website - http://www.flipkart.com

I can make it stay relevant to the layout, but the layout in the above given website simply stays in place, as if we're zooming on an image. HOW could that be replicated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-responsive design. You are advised to avoid building websites that way. However, to build a website like the one you referenced, you would use pixels to set the size of your CSS elements instead of %.
Something like that:

```
.list-item{border-right:solid 1px #ccc;padding:15px 12px 11px 12px}
```